# Different models with gensim Word2Vec on python

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I am trying to apply the word2vec model implemented in the library gensim in python. I have a list of sentences (each sentences is a list of words).

For instance let us have:

```
sentences=[['first','second','third','fourth']]*n
```

and I implement two identical models:

```
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sententes, min_count=1,size=2)
model2=gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=1,size=2)
```

I realize that the models sometimes are the same, and sometimes are different, depending on the value of n.

For instance, if n=100 I obtain

```
print(model['first']==model2['first'])
True
```

while, for n=1000:

```
print(model['first']==model2['first'])
False
```

How is it possible?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually the second case, when the result of the text is True, is with n=5000

Comment: In the code you pasted, `model` is training on `sententes` and model2 is training on `sentences`. Is this a copy error or is that your actual code?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is only a copy error.

Comment: I don't understand how this `model['first']==model2['first']` evaluates to `True`, shouldn't it evaluate to `True, True` since your embedding is in 2-space (`size=2`)?

Comment: did my post answer your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the `gensim` [documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html), there is some randomization when you run `Word2Vec`:

> `seed` = for the random number generator. Initial vectors for each word are seeded with a hash of the concatenation of word + str(seed). Note that for a fully deterministically-reproducible run, you must also limit the model to a single worker thread, to eliminate ordering jitter from OS thread scheduling.

Thus if you want to have reproducible results, you will need to set the seed:

```
In [1]: import gensim

In [2]: sentences=[['first','second','third','fourth']]*1000

In [3]: model1 = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences, min_count = 1, size = 2)

In [4]: model2 = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences, min_count = 1, size = 2)

In [5]: print(all(model1['first']==model2['first']))
False

In [6]: model3 = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences, min_count = 1, size = 2, seed = 1234)

In [7]: model4 = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences, min_count = 1, size = 2, seed = 1234)

In [11]: print(all(model3['first']==model4['first']))
True
```

Comment: In Python 3, reproducibility between interpreter launches also requires use of the PYTHONHASHSEED environment variable to control hash randomization. So, you need run Evan.oman's script by type in terminal `PYTHONHASHSEED=0 python <script_name>.py`