# Issues defining a gensim word2vec based custom sklearn transformer

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I've just started learning coding in Python and trying to use it for text classification purposes. To be able to create an `sklearn` pipeline (but also to learn how to define and use classes), I'd like to build a custom `word2vec` transformer. Example code to illustrate my issue (`doc` is a list of list of tokens):

```
from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

class GensimVectorizer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, n_dim = 64, n_context = 2):
        self.n_dim = n_dim
        self.n_context = n_context
    def fit(self, X):
        self.model = Word2Vec(X, size = self.n_dim, 
                              window = self.n_context, 
                              min_count = 1, sample = 1e-3, workers = 4)
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        return self.model.wv[X]

vect = GensimVectorizer()
vect.fit(doc)
vect.transform('word')
```

This is giving me different results compared to the code below. What am I doing wrong?

```
w2v_model = Word2Vec(doc, size = 64, window = 2, min_count = 1, sample = 1e-3, workers = 4)
w2v_model.wv['word']
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745250/different-models-with-gensim-word2vec-on-python). 'Issue' is caused due to randomization when running word2vec. Solved by setting a seed paramater and limiting the model to a single worker thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `sklearn` wrapper for `gensim`'s word2vec model like the following.

```
>>> from gensim.test.utils import common_texts
>>> from gensim.sklearn_api import W2VTransformer
>>>
>>> # Create a model to represent each word by a 10 dimensional vector.
>>> model = W2VTransformer(size=10, min_count=1, seed=1)
>>>
>>> # What is the vector representation of the word 'graph'?
>>> wordvecs = model.fit(common_texts).transform(['graph', 'system'])
>>> assert wordvecs.shape == (2, 10)
```

Read more [here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/sklearn_api/w2vmodel.html)